# How do I replace json property value in multiple places using JavaScript in Apigee

Tags: javascript, apigee

I need to replace multiple occurrence of property value in a json request using JavaScript. I have tried this in JSFiddle and it worked but the same code in an Apigee JavaScript policy is not replacing the value.

I have json data as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "app1",
        "groups": [
            {
                "desc": "this is a test group",
                "id": "test1",
                "name": "test grp45"
            },
            {
                "desc": "this is another test group",
                "id": "test2",
                "name": "test group 2"
            }
        ],
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "app2",
        "groups": [
            {
                "desc": "this is a test group",
                "id": "test3",
                "name": "test group 4"
            },
            {
                "desc": "this is another test group",
                "id": "test4",
                "name": "test group 4"
            }
        ],
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "Name": "app3",
        "groups": [
            {
                "desc": "this is a test group",
                "id": "test5",
                "name": "test group 5"
            },
            {
                "desc": "this is another test group",
                "id": "test6",
                "name": "test group 6"
            }
        ],
        "id": "3"
    }
]
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
var val = context.getVariabl("request.content");
context.setVariable("val", val);

function findAndReplace(val1, value, replacevalue) {
    for (var x in val1) {
        if (typeof val1[x] == typeof {}) {
            findAndReplace(val1[x], value, replacevalue);
        }
        if (val1[x] == value) {
            val1["name"] = replacevalue;
            //break; // uncomment to stop after first replacement
        }
    }
}
findAndReplace(val, "test1", "img");
var result = JSON.stringify(val);
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
context.setVariable("response.content", obj);
```

I want to replace the value of "test1" to "img".

Answer (score 1):

First, you're setting `response.content` with the parsed `obj`. You'd want:

```
context.setVariable("response.content", result);
```

...instead, because the flow variable needs to be a string, not a JavaScript object.

Second, you're getting `request.content` and then setting `response.content`. You probably only want one or the other, especially considering that likely this policy is attached to the request *OR* the response flow, not both (you can't set the request in the response flow, and `content.response` would be overwritten by the target response).

Use the Apigee trace tool to see where in the flow your policy is executing, and to inspect the variables being set -- this will help you figure out what you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above you have a couple of things to do to get this to work.

First I would suggest you use two policies. The javascript sample above would be called in the request flow - the one above would store a stringified version of the object into an intermediate flow variable say "foo" as below:

```
var val = JSON.parse(context.getVariable("request.content"));
findAndReplace(val, "test1", "img");
context.setVariable("foo",JSON.stringify(val));
```

In the response flow you can then use an assign message policy to insert "foo" into the response. As below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="assignFoo">
    <DisplayName>assignFoo</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Set>
        <Headers/>
        <Payload contentType="application/json; charset=utf-8">{foo}</Payload>
        <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
        <ReasonPhrase>OK</ReasonPhrase>
    </Set>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="response" />
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</AssignMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

This converts the JSON into string

```
JSON.stringify(json).replace("test1", "img")
```

and then you could convert it back to JSON with replaced values

```
JSON.parse(json)
```